# Using System Proxies with Curl

Tags: curl, pycurl

I have VPN installed that changes system's proxy network settings.

The new proxy works well with all browsers, viz. Firefox, Chrome etc.
And even with Python.

However, when I use Curl it uses my original IP address.

I tried this on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Can someone please advise, how I can make curl use system's `default` proxy settings.

I tried the following but none worked. They all give me my original IP address

```
curl -s --x 127.0.0.1 checkip.dyndns.org
curl -s --x 127.0.0.1:8080 checkip.dyndns.org
curl -s --proxy http://127.0.0.1 checkip.dyndns.org
```

I cannot use direct proxy because I do not know the proxy and port.
Neither can I use any proxy authentication since,
It is updated in the system automatically by VPN

Thanks in advance